# How array_filter is returning an object

Tags: php

I was following a tutorial and came across this,let's say I'm having an array of posts(**objects**) having two properties:

title of the post and the status (is it published or not). 
and in my code I want to return those posts who are not published yet. 
I know there are various ways to do that but in the tutorial the code shown was like this

```php
$posts = [
    new Post("My First Post",false),
    new Post("My Second Post",true),
    new Post("My Third Post",false),
    new Post("My Fourth Post",false),
    new Post("My Fifth Post",true),
    ];


$unpulishedPost = array_filter( $posts,function ($post){
    return !$post->published;
});
```

I can't get my head around how does return actually returns the entire post object when it should only returns an array of booleans shouldn't the code be like so

```php
$unpulishedPost = array_filter( $posts,function ($post){
     if(!$post->published) 
     return $post;
});
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php: _“Iterates over each value in the array passing them to the callback function. **If the callback function returns TRUE, the current value from array is returned into the result array.**”_ - the return value of the callback function is only used to decide whether the original element is kept in the result array or not; it is not used _as_ the element to insert into the result.

Comment: `array_filter()` won't transform the array, only filter it.

Comment: `array_map` uses the return value of the callback to replace the value in the array, i.e. it would do what you expect here. `array_filter` uses the return value of the callback to decide whether the value should be omitted from the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Post {
    public $title;
    public $isPublished;

    public function __construct($title, $isPublished) {
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->isPublished = $isPublished;
    }
}

$posts = [
    new Post("My First Post", false),
    new Post("My Second Post", true),
    new Post("My Third Post", false),
    new Post("My Fourth Post", false),
    new Post("My Fifth Post", true),
    ];


$unpublishedPosts = array_filter($posts, function($post) {
    return !$post->isPublished;
});

var_dump($unpublishedPosts);
```

This filter will return only the unpublished posts.

```
array(3) {
    [0] =>
    class Post#1 (2) {
      public $title =>
      string(13) "My First Post"
      public $isPublished =>
      bool(false)
    }
    [2] =>
    class Post#3 (2) {
      public $title =>
      string(13) "My Third Post"
      public $isPublished =>
      bool(false)
    }
    [3] =>
    class Post#4 (2) {
      public $title =>
      string(14) "My Fourth Post"
      public $isPublished =>
      bool(false)
    }
  }
```

Array_filter returns the **argument** of the filter callback, if the return value is true. Else it won't be pushed into the resulting array. In that way you can apply your own rules.

Comment: I think OP is asking *when it should only returns an array of booleans*, so as far as I can tell - they are expecting the output to be just an array of the `$isPublished` flags.

Comment: @NigelRen Ah, now I see and will complete my answer. Thanks for the hint.